# How can i optimize this c# code?

Tags: c#, optimization

I have converted my `Datatable` to `json` string use the following method...

```
public string GetJSONString(DataTable Dt)
{
    string[] StrDc = new string[Dt.Columns.Count];
    string HeadStr = string.Empty;
    for (int i = 0; i < Dt.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        StrDc[i] = Dt.Columns[i].Caption;
        HeadStr += "\"" + StrDc[i] + "\" : \"" + StrDc[i] + i.ToString() + "¾" + "\",";
    }
    HeadStr = HeadStr.Substring(0, HeadStr.Length - 1);
    StringBuilder Sb = new StringBuilder();

    Sb.Append("{\"" + Dt.TableName + "\" : [");
    for (int i = 0; i < Dt.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        string TempStr = HeadStr;
        Sb.Append("{");
        for (int j = 0; j < Dt.Columns.Count; j++)
        {
            if (Dt.Rows[i][j].ToString().Contains("'") == true)
            {
                Dt.Rows[i][j] = Dt.Rows[i][j].ToString().Replace("'", "");
            }
            TempStr = TempStr.Replace(Dt.Columns[j] + j.ToString() + "¾", Dt.Rows[i][j].ToString());
        }
        Sb.Append(TempStr + "},");
    }
    Sb = new StringBuilder(Sb.ToString().Substring(0, Sb.ToString().Length - 1));
    Sb.Append("]}");
    return Sb.ToString();
}
```

Is this fair enough or still there is margin for optimization to make it execute faster.... Any suggestion...

Comment: Aside from anything else, I'd strongly advise you to start using camelCase for your local variables (start them with a lower case letter) for the sake of convention.

Comment: Does it do what you expect it to?

Comment: @Jon - I didn't have the heart so tell Pandy that his code hurts my eyes. lol.   Pandiya - I have written json serializers in the distant past. I would strongly advise against it. JSON.net or something similar will server you much better in the long run. Sure you may have a specialized need right now, but how far is this snippet going to take you? Learn to use a library. It's like learning to fish. ;-)

Comment: @sky and @jon i making using of this json string in jquery... I just want to know am i appending my string to make it faster or not...

Comment: @sky definitely i do so to learn a library...

Comment: @Sky Sanders - I'd say learning to use a library is like going to the fishmongers and buying fish fillets - it really takes all the pain, room for error and risk of stabbing yourself out of the equation  ;)

Comment: @Pandiya: The point is that it's worth learning a JSON library in .NET (e.g. JSON.NET) rather than doing all this yourself.

Comment: @jon cheers for pointing this out...

Comment: @Rob - +1 for the stabbing. We all do it on the way. Pandiya is using a chainsaw. (jk p) My point is that if you find yourself munging strings to send json you _WILL_ regret it. soon. Use a library and serialize this in one call and then make your parsing adjustments on the JS side. Things are more laid back there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before asking if you can optimise it to make it execute faster, the first question you need to *ask yourself* is, does it run fast enough for me? Premature optimisation is the curse of all of us (I know I've done it!). You could spend hours trying to micro-optimise this code, which might take it from taking, for example, 20ms to execute down to 15ms. Yes that'd be a reduction of 25%, but would 5ms really be worth 2 hours of your time? More importantly, would it provide enough of a benefit to your end users to warrant it?

Have you considered using the [JsonSerializer from "Newtonsoft"](http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx)? This may well be "quick enough", is fairly widely used and is thus more likely to be correct overall than anything I, or you, can write first time round.

Purely from a readability perspective (that may also allow the C# compiler / CLR to improve thing for you) you could consider changing long bits of string concatenation such as:

```
HeadStr += "\"" + StrDc[i] + "\" : \"" + StrDc[i] + i.ToString() + "¾" + "\",";
```

To:

```
HeadStr += string.Format("\"{0}\" : \"{0}{1}¾\",", strDc[i], i);
```

But for any changes you do make. Measure, Rinse, Repeat =)

Comment: @Rob as others suggested it would be better using a library?

Comment: @Pandiya, yes, almost always and certainly in this case if you're trying to write a Json Serialiser to use in production code. If, however, this is an exercise to gain understanding of how you'd write a serialiser, then carry right on =)

Answer (score 4):

There may well be ways of getting it to execute faster - but do you have any indication that you *need* it to execute faster? Do you have a good reason to believe this is a significant bottleneck in your code? If so, benchmark the code with some real data and profile the routine to work out where the time is going.

Answer (score 1):

You could tidy up some bits:

1. Use `string.Format()` to avoid long `x + y + z` sequences. This may or may not make things faster (it would be marginal either way).
2. You usually don't need `.toString()` when concatenating.

You could also pass in the `StringBuffer` to be populated, so that the caller might have the opportunity to bundle up several such operations into a single `StringBuffer`.

These suggestions are focused more on tidiness than performance, which I think should be the real focus unless this code is presenting as a bottleneck in your profiling.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think it needs optimization? Is it really slow on some DataTables?
I'd just serialize DataTable with something like newton JSON serializer, if it's serializable at all.

Comment: It's a DataTable. nuff said. If you cannot serialize a data table, umm.. well there is always golf.

Answer (score 0):

**Refactor** your code, use a tool like ReSharper, JustCode etc to tidy it up a bit. Extract methods and use individual tests ( Test Driven Development-ish ) to find bottlenecks in your code and then tweak those.

But your first step should be: **Refactor!**

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the code isn't speed, but that it's not cleaned up. I've done some clean-up, but you could probably do even more:

```
public string GetJSONString2(DataTable table)
{
    StringBuilder headStrBuilder = new StringBuilder(table.Columns.Count * 5); //pre-allocate some space, default is 16 bytes
    for (int i = 0; i < table.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        headStrBuilder.AppendFormat("\"{0}\" : \"{0}{1}¾\",", table.Columns[i].Caption, i);
    }
    headStrBuilder.Remove(headStrBuilder.Length - 1, 1); // trim away last ,

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(table.Rows.Count * 5); //pre-allocate some space
    sb.Append("{\"");
    sb.Append(table.TableName);
    sb.Append("\" : [");
    for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        string tempStr = headStrBuilder.ToString();
        sb.Append("{");
        for (int j = 0; j < table.Columns.Count; j++)
        {
            table.Rows[i][j] = table.Rows[i][j].ToString().Replace("'", "");
            tempStr = tempStr.Replace(table.Columns[j] + j.ToString() + "¾", table.Rows[i][j].ToString());
        }
        sb.Append(tempStr + "},");
    }
    sb.Remove(sb.Length - 1, 1); // trim last ,
    sb.Append("]}");
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: @mikeal what is the use of pre allocating?

Comment: @pandiya You allocate space in the stringbuilder for the data you add to it. A StringBuilder has underlying storage, which default is 16 bytes. When this is exceeded it will allocate a bigger buffer, and copy the old contents to the new buffer. By pre-allocation a buffer of the expected end size, it will not have to re-allocate a new buffer as you add more and more data. It will make the code a bit faster as you allocate fewer objects. Same goes for List's as well.

Answer (score -2):

I would suggest a different solution,if you are using .net 3.0 or 3.5

instead of doing this

1. Convert datatable into xml
2. use xmlserializer to convert the xml to your domain object
3. Using JavaScriptSerializer(System.Web.Extensions.dll) to serialize the domain object to json string.